# Bluetooth streaming fetch on background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-bluetooth

I'm aware of background fetching ability to fetch data from time to time and there are questions regarding this on SO. [See 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944876/ios-ble-how-to-keep-app-active-in-the-background) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832681/how-to-retrive-data-from-bluetooth-when-app-in-background-ios). There are only [few cases in which an app can run in background](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-001).

But then, how can we develop an app to process data sent in streaming by a device? In my case I have a wearable that continuously sends information to the phone. If the app goes on background, the system eventually suspends the app, disconnecting the device. When the app is taken again to the foreground it does not resume but starts over.

My guess is that there is no workaround, but I want to ask here in case there are more use cases for background constant data fetching.

Comment: Bluetooth background mode and Core Bluetooth state restoration should support this as long as the device is using notify operations when it has data. If your app needs to continually poll the device then I don't believe that there is a solution. If your device does use notify and you believe you have implemented background mode and state restoration then you should edit your question to show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using '**UsesBluetooth LE accessories**' in background modes in Capabilities.

[image]

Also configure the plist file.

[image]

Comment: This is already enabled in my app but the OS keeps suspending the app after a while on the background.